# Virtualenv: Sourcing bin/activate does not work; no feedback given

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv

Been wrestling with this for a couple of hours. I installed virtualenv using easy_install. Then I did a

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages django
```

When I execute:

```
source django/bin/activate
```

I get a new line prompt with absolutely no feedback

```
rtaibah@rtaibah-Ubuntu ~ $
```

My console does not indicate that I am in a virtual environment. I confirmed this by running

```
easy_install django
```

And I get permission errors, which is not supposed to happen.I am running Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe source bin/activate or . bin/activate

Comment: the . bin/activate did it. Thanks. Any idea why source isn't working?

Comment: Probably because you are inside the django dir. Even `source bin/activate` should work

Comment: No. It doesn't matter, I tried it from ~/ from ~/Python and from ~/Python/django.

Answer (score 2):

Source with `source` instead of `virtualenv`

```
source django/bin/activate
```

You should see something like

```
(django)rtaibah@rtaibah-Ubuntu ~ $
```

Comment: Sorry my bad. I meant I used "source django/bin/activate" NOT "virtualenv django/bin/activate"

Comment: Do you see `new python executable in django/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.` on creating the virtualenv?

Comment: Yes I do. It also creates a directory with the proper files in it